# How do I make an element have a size of 100% relative to all the other elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar at the top of my screen and I also want to have an iframe under it that covers the rest of the screen. How would I make it so the iframe does not get cut off when I do something like `width: 100%; height: 100%`. This is referencing the body so the iframe is created at 100vw and 100vh. Because the navbar is already covering a portion of the screen some of the iframe is forced under. Is there any way I can force the iframe to be as large as it can be without exceeding the screen size and not hardcoding it?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: skyblue;
}

iframe {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* I dont want to hardcode this value */
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="navbar">
  <a>navbar</a>
</div>

<iframe src="https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"</iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Please include your attempt in the question, not only on an external site. You can likely use Stack Snippets to do so (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar).

Comment: If you know how tall the navbar is, you can just use `calc` (like `height: calc(100vh - <height of navbar>);`) In your case, even easier, since `#navbar` is already in `vh`. Just make `iframe` have `height: 90vh`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS - Height of 100% minus #px - Header and Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587582/css-height-of-100-minus-px-header-and-footer)

Answer (score 0):

You have added `z-index:-1;` for the iframe. This forces the iframe under the navbar.

Try removing it.